# Adding a horizontal and vertical scroll bar for d3-2way-tree for multilevel tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I was referring to d3 widget, http://bl.ocks.org/kanesee/5d6c48bffd4ea31201fb . I want the tree to be grown further more both at the top and bottom, As the page canvas is fixed I want to add scroll bars so that when the graph grows i should be able to see the chart completely.

```
{
    "name": "Heirachy",
    "parents": [
        {
            "name": "Parent1",
            "isparent": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Parent2",
            "isparent": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Parent3",
            "isparent": true,
            "parents": [
                { 
                    "name" : "inner-parent3",
                    "isparent" : true,
                    "parents":[
                        {
                            "name" : "inner-most-parent3",
                            "isparent" : true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                { 
                    "name" : "outer-parent3",
                    "isparent" : true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Childern1",
            "isparent": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Childern2",
            "isparent": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Childern3",
            "isparent": false,
            "children": [
                { 
                    "name" : "inner-1-children3",
                    "isparent" : false
                },
                { 
                    "name" : "inner-2-children3",
                    "isparent" : false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Childern4",
            "isparent": false
        }
    ]
}
```

This my json data, it makes tree to grow vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a div and add this to the CSS:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: I have added sample json which i was mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

just include overflow:auto; in css to perticular div

```
overflow:auto;
```

**new**

Add parent div for #categoryHierarchy div

HTML

```
<div id="parentDiv">
  <div id="categoryHierarchy"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parentDiv {
   margin:0 auto;
   overflow:auto;
   max-width:960px; // set width according to your requirement
   max-height:448px; // set height according to your requirement
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Work. The Canvas size remains fixed and scroll bars are disabled

Comment: add parent div for the #categoryHierarchy div and apply above style for that

Comment: If you see in Concept-graph.js file they have fixed the size, i,e in 4th line h=580

Comment: I have changed my json, which grows the graph further.So i want to add a scroll bar

Comment: then, use specific height and width for the html div as shown in above css it gives you scroll bar.

Comment: No it doesn't help. May I need to make the size dynamic in the js itself